# Android threads in app and service

Tags: android, java-threads

I have an Android app which has a long-running service.

Is the thread (in which the service's methods are called by Android) the same thread that Android uses to call the app's methods (for Activities, etc.)?

If so, is that guaranteed somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According android documentation:

> A service runs in the main thread of its hosting process—the service does not create its own thread and does not run in a separate process (unless you specify otherwise). This means that, if your service is going to do any CPU intensive work or blocking operations (such as MP3 playback or networking), you should create a new thread within the service to do that work. By using a separate thread, you will reduce the risk of Application Not Responding (ANR) errors and the application's main thread can remain dedicated to user interaction with your activities.

To process service requests in separate thread you need directly manipulate the threads. Or you can extend [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html).

Also you can start the service in separate process. To do that you need declare it in manifest:

```
<service
  android:name="WordService"
  android:process=":my_process" 
  android:icon="@drawable/icon"
  android:label="@string/service_name"
  >
</service>
```

You can find more info here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html